# Python - Back to the top loop with while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am programming 4-parametric RAINFLOW method. So the idea is is to get standard loading cycles, that are defined with 4 requirements, out of a load history, which normally consists of a few 1000, 10000 or even more points (force-time). There are 2 standard cycles that you are looking for in this load history, a rising and a falling one[image: example here]. Both are shown in the picture. You always start at the beginning and try to find one of the cycles, if you dont succeed from the first points, you move one point up (j=j+1) and start again. Once you find a cycle, you delete the 2nd and 3rd point (y1 and y2) and start back from the beginning.

I did the alghoritm in a way where it first determines if the second points of the load history is higher from the first one or lower, so that it knows for which cycle to look first (from where to start). From there on it is just searching for the requirements, that are also listed in the picture.

**My problem:**
 I would like to program this in a way where in case that non of the 2 cycles are found, the program would add a +1 to the j and start from the top again and would do so until a cycle would be found. I did use the while loop and tried to do with the true/false but it doeasnt work. Nothing really happens.... if some1 has an idea.

y is just a short example of the vector of random points.

```
y = [0.00, 2.00, 4.00, 5.00, 5.50, 6.00, 5.00, 4.00, 3.20, 3.50, 4.00, 4.50,   4.70, 4.80, 5.00, 4.50, 4.30, 4.00, 3.00, 2.00, 1.00, 
 1.50, 2.50, 4.00, 4.50, 2.50, 1.50, 0.50, 0.30, 2.50, 3.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 5.00, 5.50, 6.00, 6.20, 5.50, 3.00]


a = []
for j in range(len(y)):
while j<(len(y)-4):
    if y[j+1] > y[j]:
        while False:
            if y[j+2] >= y[j] and y[j+3] >= y[j+1]:
                True 
                a.append(y[j+1])                
                del y[j+1]
                a.append(y[j+1])                
                del y[j+1]
            else:
                j = j+1
                if y[j] >= y[j+2] and y[j+1]>= y[j+3]:
                    stavek = True
                    a.append(y[j+1])                    
                    del y[j+1]
                    a.append(y[j+1])                    
                    del y[j+1]
                else:
                    j=j+1
                    False

    elif y[j+1] < y[j]:
        while False:
            if y[j+2] <= y[j] and y[j+3] <= y[j+1]:                    
                a.append(y[j+1])
                del y[j+1]
                a.append(y[j+1])
                del y[j+1]
            else:
                j = j+1
                if y[j] <= y[j+2] and y[j+1]<= y[j+3]:
                    stavek = True
                    a.append(y[j+1])
                    del y[j+1]
                    a.append(y[j+1])
                    del y[j+1]
                else:
                    j=j+1
                    False
```

Comment: If you post code, you should tag language. It helps people to find your question and also affects the syntax coloring.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this forum and not used to it yet :)

Comment: There is good information in the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `while False` will never execute. You need to rewrite the loop into the form of `while True: {loop stuff here} if not condition(): break` or `while not condition: {loop}`

Answer (score 0):

`while False` will never execute because the condition is not met. Perhaps you should look into a `do` -> `while` so it runs atleast once, and introduce a new variable that you would set to true or false to continue looping.